# JS - Dice roll twice, want to check for double roll in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a crazy idea I had. Basically trying to keep the code as compact as possible I came up with this:

```
function swordAtk() {
    // gets two attack dice / rolls
    var rolls = 2, i=0;
    var d6 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
    var d6res = 0;

    while (i < rolls) {
        d6res = d6;
        d6res += d6res;
        i++
    }
    $('#attack').html("You attack for " + d6res + ".");
}
```

This works perfectly to show the result of two rolls added up, however I want to check the results of each roll against each other to see if they are the same. If they are the same, a bonus die is rolled.

I could separate each roll out into different variables, but if there's a way to do it inside this compact loop I'd rather do that.

Comment: Won't they always be the same?

Comment: They will. This code is bugged

Comment: Is "rolls" always = 2? And if it's the same number, just add another dice?

Comment: Should it work with any number of dies and check if every roll is unique? Or just if there are no two consecutive rolls with the same result?

Comment: @YoannAugen To answer your question, yes. In this particular function they rolls will stay the same, but I plan to have different functions that contain different number of rolls.

Comment: @pawel I suppose working with any number of dies would be ideal here.

Comment: @user2766423 ok, added to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that will work with more than 2 dice as well and checks if all rolls are the same.

```
function swordAtk() {
    var rolls = 2;
    var total = 0;
    var dice = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= rolls; i++) {
        var die = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        dice.push(die);
        total += die;
    }

    // Check if all dice have the same roll
    if ($.grep(dice, function (elem) {
        return elem === dice[0];
    }).length == rolls) {
        var die = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        total += die;
    }

    $('#attack').html("You attack for " + d6res + ".");
}
```

You can find a demonstration of this in this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly4GH/)**.

Comment: Your fiddle is much more comprehensive than this code. I think your fiddle may be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You code is bugged. It's roll alway the same dice.

Here some ideas:

If you will always need to throw two dices, don't make a loop. Two variables will be more clear.

```
function swordAtk() {
    var d6_1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
    var d6_2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
    var d6_bonus = 0
    if (d6_1 == d6_2) {
        d6_bonus = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1)
    }
    $('#attack').html("You attack for " + (d6_1 + d6_2 + d6_bonus) + ".");
}
```

If you realy want to make a loop (there is no reason for me). It will be something like that :

```
function swordAtk() {
    var rolls = 2, i=0;
    var d6 = 0;
    var d6res = 0;
    var last_d6 = 0;

    while (i < rolls) {
        d6 =  Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
        if (d6 == last_d6) {
            d6res += Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
        }
        last_d6 = d6;
        d6res += d6;
        i++
    }
    $('#attack').html("You attack for " + d6res + ".");
}
```

But it's not shorter and that will not work well if rolls variable change.

Answer (score 0):

Here a code that work for any number of dies. I wasn't sure about the double thing so i assumed that if in the throw, there's a double, it roll another dice. It also keep every roll in an array:

```
function swordAtk() {
    // gets two attack dice / rolls
    var rolls = 2, i=0;
    var rollsRes = [];
    var double = false;

    while (i < rolls) {
        var roll = Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1);
        if(rollsRes.indexOf(roll) !== -1) double = true;

        rollsRes.push(roll);

        i++
    }

    if(double) rollsRes.push(Math.floor((Math.random()*6) + 1));

    console.log(rollsRes);

    var total = (function(arr){
        var rtnInt = 0;
        while(arr) rtnInt += arr.shift();
        return rtnInt;
    })(rollsRes)

    $('#attack').html("You attack for " + total + ".");
}

swordAtk();
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/h6EdA/

Answer (score 0):

Decided to play around with this.. code and comments are in fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2ECRs/

```
var rolls = 2;
var rollArray = [];

function rollDice() {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
}

for (i=0; i<rolls; i++) {
    rollArray[i] = rollDice();
}

var total = rollArray[0] + rollArray[1];

if (rollArray[0] == rollArray[1]) {
    rollArray[2] = rollDice();
    var extra = rollArray[2];
    var total = total + extra;
}

if (rollArray.length == 2){
    $('#attack').html("Roll 1: " + rollArray[0] + "<br />Roll 2: " + rollArray[1] + "<br /><strong>You attack for " + total + ".</strong>");
} else {
    $('#attack').html("Doubles!<br />Roll 1: " + rollArray[0] + "<br />Roll 2: " + rollArray[1] + "<br />Bonus Roll: " + extra + "<br /><strong>You attack for " + total + ".</strong>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method is a prototype of the Hero object. Method for each new Hero object can be used to return dice roll. 
If hero1 = new Hero than:
hero1.diceRoll(2) returns random score of rolling dice twice, 
hero1.diceRoll(3) returns random score of rolling dice triple, and so on.

```
Hero.prototype.diceRoll = function(diceNum) {
        var diceScore = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < diceNum; i++){
          var diceScoreR =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
          diceScore = diceScore + diceScoreR;
        }
        return diceScore;
      };
```

Comment: Please add some description of why this code solves the problem